# Rewriting (or bounding) $\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{1}{(1-r)^j}$ in terms of the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know the common formula:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty r^j = \frac{1}{1-r},
$$
for $r<1$.

What about $\frac{1}{(1-r)^k}$ though? I'm asking this because I want to utilise rewrite

$$\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{1}{(1-r)^j}$$

for $r<1$ and possibly connect that with the exponential function.

Comment: If $r<0$ then $\frac{1}{1-r}<1$ so you can use the formula you know.

Comment: @MarcMagaña Sorry, that was a typo. I corrected it to $r<1$.

Comment: It is a geometric series too. Think of it as $\sum_{j=0}^k\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)^j$ and use the partial sum of the geometric to get what you want. If $0\leq r<1$ then the sum diverges.

Comment: @MarcMagaña Is there no way to relate it to the exponential function, e.g. of the form $\exp(-Ck)$ or something?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-r)^j} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-r}}$$
with natural restrictions on $r$. And for finite sum:
$$\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{(1-r)^j} = \frac{1- \frac{1}{(1-r)^n}}{1-\frac{1}{1-r}}-1$$

Comment: In my question, the sum is until $k\in\mathbb{N}$, not $\infty$.

Comment: You can find that here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: I looked to your first formula and write accordingly. If you would like to have formula for finite sum, then it comes from the same way: consider sum for geometric progression.

Comment: @MarcMagaña I couldn't find it there.

Comment: @JasonBorn $\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$.